# Check whether variable conforms to string format

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need a way to check whether the string contents of a variable conforms to a certain format.  An example of the format I need is 52M-14Jun04-1, i.e. 11A-11Aaa11-1.

Occasionally there are also strings that contain an asterisk in place of the first letter, i.e. 11*11Aaa11-1.

Many thanks,
Jens

Comment: What things have you tried?

Comment: Nothing yet I'm afraid, haven't found anything.  Wondered if regex could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with using [`LIKE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

```
DECLARE @Input varchar(20) = '52M-14Jun04-1'
DECLARE @Result varchar(20)

SELECT @Result =
    (CASE WHEN 
        @Input LIKE '[0-9][0-9][A-Z*]-[0-9][0-9][A-Z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]'
     THEN 
         'Matches'
     ELSE
         'Does not match'
     END)
```

An explanation of the pattern:

- `[0-9]` Any digit between 0 and 9
- `[A-Z*]` Any character A through Z (uppercase) or *
- `-` A hyphen
- `[a-z]` Any character a through z (lowercase)